# Receive an high rate of UDP packets with python

Tags: python, performance, sockets, udp, fpga

I'm working with python in order to receive a stream of UDP packets from an FPGA, trying to lose as few packets as possible.
The packet rate goes from around 5kHz up to some MHz and we want to take data in a specific time window (acq_time in the code).
We have this code now:

```
BUFSIZE=4096
dataSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dataSock.settimeout(0.1)
dataSock.bind((self.HOST_IP, self.HOST_PORT))
time0=time.time()
data_list = []
while time.time()-time0<acq_time:
     fast_acquisition(data_list)

def fast_acquisition(data_list_tmp):
    data, addr = dataSock.recvfrom(self.BUFSIZE)
    data_list_tmp.append(data) 
    return len(data)
```

And after the acquisition we save our data_list on disk.

This code is meant to be as simple and fast as possible, but it's still too slow and we lose too many packets even at 5kHz, and we think that this happens because while we read, and store in the list one packet and check the time, the next one (ore ones) arrives and is lost.
Is there any way to keep the socket open? Can we open multiple sockets "in series" with parallel processing, so that when we are saving the file from the first the second can receive another packet?
We can even think to use another language only to receive and store the packets on disk.

Comment: `acq_time` is a constant value ?

Comment: Yes, acq_time is a constant value (few seconds)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) (*which is implemented in C*) to capture the UDP traffic, since it's faster than [`python`](https://www.python.org/):

```
#!/bin/bash

iface=$1 # interface, 1st arg
port=$2  # port, 2nd arg

tcpdump -i $iface -G acq_time_in_seconds -n udp port $port -w traffic.pcap
```

And then you can use e.g. [`scapy`](https://scapy.net/) to process that traffic

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

scapy_cap = rdpcap('traffic.pcap')
for packet in scapy_cap:
    # process packets...
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try on Monday. Do you think that in a dump like this (a lot of small packages) the bottleneck will come from the Ethernet connection or from the processing speed?

Comment: I can't say about the Ethernet connection, since I don't know what kind of network are we talking about. **But** because python is not like **C**, a python network sniffer is slower than one implemented in C. Also I suppose that the processing of each packet adds an additional bottleneck, but I can't measure it...

Comment: Correct. Don’t count on scapy to receive high packet rates... that’s a python restriction. I would however note that you could use a `L2ListenTcpdump` socket which calls tcpdump for the capture, then handles the packet in scapy

Comment: Switching from Python to C is indeed the first thing you need to do. Python is pretty much the slowest language out there. There is approximately a 300x performance disadvantage compared to C. You can also use Wireshark to capture UDP frames.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why UDP packets can be lost, and certainly the speed of being able to take them off the socket queue and store them can be a factor, at least eventually. However, even if you had a dedicated C language program handling them, it's unlikely you'll be able to receive all the UDP packets if you expect to receive more than a million a second.

The first thing I'd do is to determine if python performance is actually your bottleneck. It is more likely in my experience that, first and foremost, you're simply running out of receive buffer space. The kernel will store UDP datagrams on your socket's receive queue until the space is exhausted. You might be able to extend that capacity a little with a C program, but you will still exhaust the space faster than you can drain the socket if packets are coming in at high enough speed.

Assuming you're running on linux, take a look at this answer for how to configure the socket's receive buffer space -- and examine the system-wide maximum value, which is also configurable and might need to be increased.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992928/1076479

(If you're not on linux, I can't really give any specific guidance, although the same factors are likely to apply.)

It is possible that you will be unable to receive packets fast enough, even with more buffer space and even in a C program. In that case, @game0ver's idea of using `tcpdump` might work better if you only need to withstand a short intense burst of packets as it uses a much lower-level interface to obtain packets (and is highly optimized). But then of course you won't just have the UDP payload, you'll have entire raw packets and will need to strip the IP and Ethernet layer headers as well before you can process them.

Comment: Yes, a millon frames per second is a challenge. May require custom software on driver level. But, no, there is no question about Python. Python is definitely the bottleneck at 5 kHz UDP. I have experienced exactly the same thing with Python.

Comment: @TimmyBrolin That is simply not true. I just wrote a toy program in python that can receive nearly 100K UDP packets / second. (And this is running inside a virtual machine, with the other system sending UDP datagrams over a wifi link -- and without doing anything to adjust the receive buffer space.) If you cannot receive 5K packets per second, you're doing something wrong, your machine is *extremely* slow, or there are other factors impacting your situation.

Comment: @GilHamilton What is your buffer size and system configuration?