# Python UDP receiver raises timeout error with high package rate while wireshark receives data

Tags: python, udp, timeout, wireshark, receiver

I'm trying to make a simple UDP receiver, using python, to read a continuous data stream from a data aquisition device. This device can be configured to send data using UDP protocol to a certain IP and port. I configured it to send two data streams on port 4000 and 4001 both to ip: 192.168.0.10 (see wireshark screenshot below). The stream to port 4001 has a higher package rate. My laptop ip for the ethernet interface used is set statically at this ip in order to receive the data. I can receive the slow stream at port 4000 which works as expected. When I use the same code and set the port to 4001 I expected to read this data stream, instead I get a timeout exception.

I expected the biggest problem with high package rate udp would be loosing data because the buffer overflows which is not a big problem since loosing some packets is acceptable for my case. However if I get a timeout exception during the socket.recv(1024) call I thought that means there is no data in the buffer? Since wireshark does receive data I don't understand what is happening.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do.

```
import socket

for i in range(3):  # try multiple times
    try:
        socket_i = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        socket_i.settimeout(5)
        socket_i.bind(('192.168.0.10', 4001))  #4000 works, 4001 does not
        raw = socket_i.recv(1024)

        socket_i.close()
        print(raw)
    except Exception as ex:  # Exception is raised when using 4001: timed out
        socket_i.close()
        print('failed')
        print(ex)
```

[Wireshark printscreen; only 1 packet from port 4000 is shown, since this stream is slow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMz0u.png)

I read similar questions:
[Receive an high rate of UDP packets with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448972/receive-an-high-rate-of-udp-packets-with-python)

Here it was concluded that python was the bottle neck. Also they received data, I don't receive anything, instead the socket.recv() times out. I don't think my package rate is that high, anyone thinks otherwise?

[Receive an high rate of UDP packets with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448972/receive-an-high-rate-of-udp-packets-with-python)

Here most of the data was received and only after some time the algorithm 'hangs on socket.recv()'. I tried increasing the buffer as suggested, using:

```
socket_i.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1024*1024*1024)
```

Various values for buffer size are tried without luck. Setting large time out did not help.

Finally I tried using 'socketserver' package (the example udp server script):

```
import socketserver

class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    This class works similar to the TCP handler class, except that
    self.request consists of a pair of data and client socket, and since
    there is no connection the client address must be given explicitly
    when sending data back via sendto().
    """

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip()
        socket = self.request[1]
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(data)
        # socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)  #don't want to send stuff back

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.UDPServer(('192.168.0.10', 4001), MyUDPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

Using port 4000 this gives the expected behaviour, for port 4001 the code hangs without doing anything (probably large timeout by default?). I guess 'socketserver' package runs ontop of'socket' package?

I hope someone can help!

## Update:

I fixed my problem by making the udp receiver using pyshark. This is a bit hacky and I'm not satisfied with the method however for now it works. I figured if wireshark receives data pyshark might work as well. Any suggestions using 'socket' package are welcome!

code for hacky udp receiver

```
import pyshark
ip = '192.168.0.10'
port = 4001
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(bpf_filter=f'dst host {ip} and dst port {port}', use_json=True, include_raw=True)

for pkt in capture.sniff_continuously():
    raw = bytearray.fromhex(pkt.udp.payload_raw[0])
    print(raw)
```

Comment: I wrote a server that sent a 582-byte packet every 4ms to port 4001 and a 118-byte packet every 40ms to port 4000 and your code receives them just fine (localhost, though).

Comment: FYI, `socketserver` is just a wrapper for `socket`.

Comment: Thank you for trying! I will try making such a server and test it on 1 pc via localhost as well. If it works via localhost, but doesn't when the data arrives from another device do you know what the problem could be? Especially since I can receive the data using Wireshark, (hence it actually arrives).

Comment: Hi I made a similar server sending over localhost as you suggested. From the receiving end I did not get the timeout error and I received the packages as expected however I did not check if there was any data loss.